# How to block 8080 but make it only accessible by port 80?

Tags: linux

I am trying to make a security group on my Linux service, running a backend service at port 8080 and I want to make sure that only Apache that runs on port 80 can access the backend service at port 8080 and no other port can.

Do note, it is the same machine, kind of like a server that has my frontend aka the website, and a backend server aka the API server.
But I wish to implement an internal firewall which basically only allows my Apache server to access this API.
But if go do a bash to my server and do a curl, the backend API should not be available.
View this as a website or html page running on port 80 and a backend API service maybe a nodejs server running at 8080. My aim is to just let this port 80 make requests to port 8080.

Basically, I am trying to implement an AWS security kind of thing, if that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no externally visible relation between Apache receiving a request on port 80 and Apache forwarding this request to an upstream service. They are simply two TCP connections.

Comment: View this as a website or html page running on port 80 and a backend API service maybe a nodejs server running at 8080. My aim is to just let this port 80 make requests to port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to implement an internal firewall which stops basically only allows my apache server to access this API. But if go do a bash to my server and do a curl, the backend API should not be available.

Option 1: Set up firewall rules using UID-based matching. In both nftables and ip[6]tables you can match on the socket owner UID, allowing only the "http" or "www-data" account.

For nftables, use the `meta skuid <user>` match (everything else would stay the same as in the IP-based example). For ip[6]tables use the `--uid-owner <user>` match option.

```
tcp dport 8080 jump {
    meta skuid "www-data" accept
    reject
}
```

When using iptables, don't forget to add both iptables *and* ip6tables rules.

Option 2: Make the backend listen on a "local" (AF_UNIX) socket instead of a TCP socket. Local sockets behave a bit like files, so you can put them in a directory restricted to only the "http" user account using regular file permissions.

```
gunicorn --bind=unix:/run/mybackend.sock myapp.wsgi:application

curl --unix-socket /run/mybackend.sock http://whatever/index.html
```

Both Apache and Nginx support proxying to a local socket; the syntax looks like:

```
ProxyPass unix:/run/mybackend.sock|http://localhost
```

Option 3: Set up HTTPS between Apache and the backend and implement mTLS, with the backend requiring a client certificate from Apache.

Option 4: Make the backend require a specific authentication header to be provided by the proxy (this is a bit risky as there are ways the header might leak).

---

Original answer:

Set up firewall rules on the backend system. If your backend server uses ufw or firewalld, look up how to configure those to restrict port 8080 to specific sources only; if it has no firewall yet, then nftables (or Ferm, or raw iptables) might be the next step.

Note that the "backend" connections from Apache **do not** come from port 80. They use a random temporary source port, like any other TCP connection generally does. So your firewall rules should be configured to match the source *IP address* of the Apache proxy, rather than the port.

```
client:13456 --> apache:80
                     ||
                 apache:23147 --> backend:8080
```

(To make it really clear, the "client-proxy" and "proxy-backend" connections are independent. At IP layer the backend only sees the proxy's address, not the client's, and the fact that Apache itself *listens on* port 80 is completely irrelevant.)

For example, in (recent versions of) nftables:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        [...]

        tcp dport 8080 jump {
            ip saddr 192.168.42.3 accept
            ip6 saddr 2001:db8:42::7 accept
            reject
        }

        [...]
    }
}
```

**Alternatively,** if the backend is running on the *same* system, it might be simpler configure the backend server to listen on (aka bind to) `::1` and/or `127.0.0.1`, i.e. the "localhost" addresses.

Once the service binds to specific local addresses, connections to the backend's other IP addresses will be implicitly rejected, as there will be nothing listening for them – while Apache on the same system will still be able to connect to the backend at `http://localhost:8080` or `[::1]:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Note that "same system" excludes VMs and even containers here, as they would have their own "localhost" separate from the host system.

---

Larger systems sometimes also use "mTLS", i.e. TLS between proxy and backend with client-certificate authentication (requiring the Apache proxy, as a client, to provide its own certificate to the backend server).

Comment: Hey, this makes sense, but I have both services on the same system and I was wondering if there was a way to implement an internal firewall. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That's a bit different question now, but yes, both iptables and nftables actually support UID-based matching.

Comment: My apologies, I lacked the knowledge to properly frame the question, so I tried my best. I do appreciate the information you have given me already. But it would be great if you can give me more insight into it as well. The iptables or the other one, maybe just a simple example to implement and practice.

Comment: Do you think I would be able to use this to establish a website or html page running on port 80 and a backend API service maybe a nodejs server running at 8080? My aim is to just let this port 80 make requests to port 8080.